# How to call dynamically helper in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

i have create one html help page like CMS and stored in database.

```
<content>
  <a href="{{dynamicUrl name="contact"}}">Contact us</a>
</content>
```

In html file write this code

```
{{{helpPage}}}
```

Is it possible call dynamicUrl in html right now in `<a>` tag show

```
<a href="{{dynamicUrl name="contact"}}">Contact us</a>
```

Comment: please elaborate what is your problem and what are you trying to achieve. I think most of us haven't understood the problem clearly

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you want to be able to parse Spacebars template tags from a template string? If so,

Add `carlevans719:dynamic-templates`, then change

```
{{{helpPage}}}
```

to:

```
{{Template.dynamic template=dynamicTemplate}}
```

And in your template `helpers`, add:

```
dynamicTemplate: function () {
  var content = getContentFromDB();
  var template = new DynamicTemplate(content);
  return template.name;
}
```

See: https://atmospherejs.com/carlevans719/dynamic-templates